# PSQL: Ignore duplicates, show most recent records in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have psql table with the following scheme. Each instance appears several times in the table, with a creation date.

[image: sample CSV]

I am interested only in the most recent ones. So filtering duplicates, show only unique ones with most recent occurrence.

My desired output would look like:

[image: output CSV]

Could you help me to find the proper query code?

I appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on(unique_id)` :

```
select distinct on(unique_id) unique_id, "text", creation_date
from table_name
order by unique_id, creation_date desc;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f88195f9b101a8415e3525871eb97f53)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. This one worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your query is something I'm missing here...
Anyway. You can sort, and pick first, you can group and pick max/min. That are simple solutions. Bigger cannon here are [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html).

If that is not enough - provide your query, I'll edit answer... we will get there! :)